# How does the HUD Display System work?

Tags: avionics, hud

I have seen a couple videos of fighter jets and commercial planes with [HUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display) systems and was wondering how do the heads up displays work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_up_display

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### HUD

The most common form of head-Up Display ([HUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display#Civil_aircraft_specific_applications)) is simply an out-of-sight display screen reflected in a transparent flat sheet of glass in the viewers line of sight out the cockpit front window.

The glass sheet is called a combiner. It combines the HUD information with the view out of the aircraft.

There are coatings for glass ([E.g.](http://www.google.com/patents/US5576886)) which allow for reflecting a monochromatic image while allowing transmission of other colors.

The display is obviously tailored for that specific use. It must avoid obscuring the view. Therefore it mostly consists of minimal light-colored lines and numerals/letters against a dark background. The dark background allows the pilot to see through the reflection to brighter objects outside - it's a bit like the matt black upper surface typically found on many car dashboards which prevents distracting unwanted images of the top of the dash being reflected into the driver's view out of the windscreen.

Here's an example from [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/boeing/companyoffices/gallery/images/commercial/737900-11.page)
[image]

A HUD display is visible on the left in the pilot's line of sight. Above it, mounted on the ceiling is the projector unit.

The Projector contains optics to make the pilot's view of the display appear to be at infinity (rather than the few feet away it is in reality). This allows the pilot to read the data while their eyes are focused on far-away real-world objects outside the aircraft (runways, weather, other aircraft etc).

### EFVS

Beyond the projection of basic flight instrument data is the use of HUDs for Enhanced Flight Vision Systems ([EFVS](http://aviationweek.com/awin/rockwell-collins-build-end-end-efvs)) which provide a kind of augmented reality display that typically uses external infra-red camera systems to identify landmarks (e.g. runway outlines) that may be obscured to the pilot due to fog etc.

Comment: Very nice improvement, thanks!

Comment: How do these systems control for parallax error? Or I assume the ones on commercial flights don't display any info that relies on precise head position?

Comment: @RoboKaren: The lens that makes the display appear at infinity happens to correct for parallax error as well. The optical element creates virtual image at infinity and in behaves as if it was really there in all regards.

Comment: You actually don't need a special coating, though it helps; the angle of the glass itself, coupled with a well-lit projection, is enough. The concept and implementation are similar to the "Pepper's Ghost" illusion.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation. But I have seen in some cars a glass that reflects all the colors, yet it's transparent. Can you explain why?

Comment: @zagoku. cheaper combiners use partially mirrored glass, this reflects all colours but has the disadvantage that it attenuates light from the outside world to a degree that is unacceptable for piloting aircraft. See link in answer re coatings.